# -10003 error when trying to start Metatrader 5 from IIS

Tags: python, fastapi, windows-server-2012, metatrader5

`-10003` error when trying to start Metatrader 5 from IIS.

I have an API created in python 3.10 and fastapi, I have it running on a Windows server and IIS 6.2.

The error comes when I try to initialize the mt5 from IIS which throws me.

```
{"message": "initialize() failed",
"error_code": [
    -10003,
    "IPC initialize failed, "
]}
```

NOTE: In my local the api works fine but there I run it using `Uvicorn`.

NOTE 2 : If I run the code directly in the console it also runs perfectly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt

login= account_number
password='password'
server='sever_name'
timeout=5000 # Number of milliseconds for timeout

try: 
    mt.initialize(login=login, password=mdp, server=server, timeout=timeout)
    print(f'MT5 initialized! Status: {mt.last_error()}')
except:
    print(f'MT5 not initialized /!\\\nStatus: {mt.last_error()}')
    mt.shutdown()
```